# Looking for an easier Skype video chat alternative

Tags: video, skype, software-rec, product-rec, chat

Is there any software 'easier to use' than Skype - ie to get a video conversation going you have to turn on the computer, make sure the speakers are turned on, make sure the web cam is connected, make sure you click answer with Video...

I would like to buy a 'single red button' which does all of the above. - Any recommendations?

**Update** @Eric Koslow comment

My original question title was "Is there any software/hardware 'easier to use' than Skype?"
So the answer is not necessarily a computer running a program, although it might be.

I realise Skype makes a good attempt at helping to ensure speakers and web cam are working and helps you to sort them out if they are not, and for a person who isnt computer phobic this should be enough. However I am interested if there is anything available that is 'easier' than this - ie I'm looking for my 'single' red button.

ie the mobile phone with video call maybe the closest answer so far, but I would prefer something as 'free' as Skype is.

Comment: I don't really understand your question.  Any program will force you to have the computer on, if you want to hear anything you'll have to turn on teh speakers, if you want to see anything you'll have to connect a web cam.  These all seem to by phyical issues not software related.

Comment: I'm looking for something that is as easy as a phone to use... that is as 'free' as Skype is... and aimed at ease of use..  I havent used this, but the idea behind it is what I want - http://eldy.eu/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like what you're after is a mobile phone with video call support.  Don't really have to do too much extra to get that working.

Comment: Skype sells phones with their service integrated. Don't know if they're easier to use than just using a computer, though.

Answer (score 4):

Gmail has a built in Video Chat over Google Talk.
Really easy.

Comment: I've purchased multiple cameras for family members, and setup Google Apps for my family domain. Everyone in my family (20+) love that they can chat with relatives while checking e-mail.

Comment: AFAIK it only works on windows.

Answer (score 1):

The program I am using for video now-a-days is [IMO.im](https://imo.im).  Its easy to use, and can in addition to video, can chat with almost any popular protocol.