# Good Video chatting application

Tags: windows-xp, video, skype, software-rec, chat

Skype eats too much CPU while video chatting (about 100%). I am not sure it's due to the camera driver or Skype. What is a light resource drain video chatting application, please?

OS: Windows XP SP3.

Comment: Operating system? Windows?

Comment: possible duplicate: http://superuser.com/questions/3913/looking-for-an-easier-skype-video-chat-alternative

Answer (score 1):

Before I moved over to Skype I used [Google Talk](http://www.google.com/talk/)

Answer (score -1):

Just try a Teamspeak 2/3 public server. Often you can make private channels on those. Teamspeak needs very little CPU!